# Laravel filter parent rows based on first row child

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relation

I'm trying this code

```
$query = Parent::where('state', 1)
         ->with(array('child'=> function ($q) use ($end_date) {
             $q->where('start_date', '<=', $end_date);
         }));

$query->whereHas("child", function ($query) use ($filter) {
            if (isset($filter["id"]) && $filter["id"] != "") {
                $query->where("id", '=', $filter["id"]);
            }
        });
```

then in **Parent Models** i have this code

```
public function child()
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Child', 'code', 'code');
}
```

I want to do something like this :

1. Get all Parent data with Child
2. Only get the first child after order by start_date descending
3. Filter Parent data using Child id based on result no.2

json example :

**Result from step-1**

```
"parent" : [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "ABC"
    "child" : [
       {
          "id" : 1,
          "star_date" : "2021-03-01"
       },
       {
          "id" : 2,
          "star_date" : "2021-03-15"
       }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "XYZ"
    "child" : [
       {
          "id" : 3,
          "star_date" : "2021-03-01"
       },
       {
          "id" : 4,
          "star_date" : "2021-03-20"
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Result from step-2** (order by start_date descending)

```
"parent" : [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "ABC"
    "child" : 
       {
          "id" : 2,
          "star_date" : "2021-03-15"
       }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "XYZ"
    "child" : 
       {
          "id" : 4,
          "star_date" : "2021-03-20"
       }
  }
]
```

**Result from step-3** (filter by child id = 2)

```
"parent" : [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "ABC"
    "child" : 
       {
          "id" : 2,
          "star_date" : "2021-03-15"
       }
  }
]
```

but i can't get the result i want..

Can anyone help me to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Filter Parent data using Child id based on result no.2" how would you filter that data, it does not make sense imo :) try to describe it further

Comment: What you want to do makes me strongly recommend to use something like [Nested sets](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset). Give it a try, it's less effort than you might think and gives you so much more performant query capabilities!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to use subquery :

```
public function lastChild()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Child::class, 'last_child_id');
    }

    public function scopeWithLastChild($query)
    {
        $query->addSelect([
                'last_child_id' => $this->lastChildSubQuery(),
            ]
        )->with('lastChild');
    }

    public function lastChildSubQuery($select_field = 'id')
    {
        return Child::selectRaw($select_field)
                       ->whereColumn('parents.code', 'childs.code')
                       ->orderByDesc('start_date')
                       ->limit(1);
    }
```

Then you can get your lastChild like so :

```
$parent = Parent::withLastChild()->first();
$parent->lastChild->[...];
```

Now if you want to filter your parent base on your last child 'id' column:

```
$parent = Parent::withLastChild()
->having('last_child_id', $filter['id'])
->first();
```

if you want any other column :

```
Parent::select()
        ->addSelect([
                'last_child_foo' => $this->lastChildSubQuery('foo'),
            ]
        )->having('last_child_foo', $filter['foo'])
         ->first();
```